# Possible to select a specific entity without knowing the key in OData?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a problem where I need to select a specific value from a specific entity from a entity set, however, I need to do it in a way without knowing the key.

This is the query I actually need:

```
odata/..../picklistLabels(locale='en_GB',optionId=10819)/label
```

However I need to program it in a way so it automatically selects the label without knowing the optionId. Is there a way to do this in OData?

Comment: Maybe something like being able to do a whole query like optionId=*query* ?

Comment: What do you have so far? Did you try to apply a filter?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think that you want to perform a navigation but you don't have a key. Unfortunately, this exact functionality isn't available, however, you can perform an expand like this:

```
odata/..../picklistLabels?$filter=locale eq 'en_GB' and optionId=10819&$expand=label
```

This will get you the same information that the other call would do but in a slightly different format, you would have to find the first element in the array and then get the label property to get that information

As an aside, if you have the option to change the server (I'm guessing not due to the sapui5 tag but it might be useful for other users) you could change the key. If the locale and the optionId are enough to identify the object, then you could make these into a composite key. Here is a link for an example within the WebAPI OData source code: https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataCompositeKeySample